# PayPal - Native Checkout SDK(Android)-invalid scope

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

[image]1

I'm using the new Native Checkout PayPal SDK for Android with Kotlin and I've been following every step in the documentation but getting - invalid scope.

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution...this issue happened because of not enabling the payment method in the App feature option in the PayPal-created application of the Paypal dashboard console.

Also, we need to enter the privacy & agreement URLs also the checkboxes to be enabled.

Comment: In my case all were checked and is working with sandbox, but didn't work on live environment @NarenTheAndroid Did it work with live environment in your case?

Comment: @SanjivDhakal did you got the answer , i am also facing same thing its working fine in sandbox but in case of live i am getting this error

Comment: @RaviOjha raise issue on github https://github.com/paypal/android-checkout-sdk , they will fix the issue from thier side, we have to do nothing, in my case they enable native checkout sdk option on merchant account, and the problem solved